# Hibernate + H2 do not update yes_no type column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2

I couldn't find an answer here or on Google.

My problem is the following : 
I have an entity with a yes_no type column

```
public class MyEntity {

  @Column(name = "IS_DELETED")
  @Type(type = "yes_no")
  private Boolean itemDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

In database, the column is a CHAR(1)

```
IS_DELETED CHAR(1) CHECK ("IS_DELETED" IN ('Y', 'N'))
```

The following code pose an issue in H2 with my JUnit tests (it runs well with Oracle when the application runs) :

```
myEntityRepositoryService.save(myEntity);
```

All the columns that are **not** yes_no type are correctly updated. I enabled some hibernate logs to check if the commit happens, if the transaction was released,... Everything is ok. All the columns are well updated **but not the yes_no column.**

I tried to set some random values in other fields (like random number) in the code just before the save. It works, the values are saved but not the boolean column.

Note that the repository service extends **org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository**

Is there a known issue with the Hibernate YesNoType? Am I doing something wrong? H2 needs a special configuration?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this. I am having similar problem with H2 and grails, moving to production. Works fine in memory when the database is recreated, but in production it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not H2. Instead, your JpaRepository is probably not leveraging Hibernate. Please make sure it's using the [Hibernate EntityManager](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/) rather than some other implementation (e.g. EclipseLink).

Comment: I already use the Hibernate Entity Manager. I'm not even sure that it would work with Oracle otherwise. But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: As a quick test, can you instead remove the `@Type(type = "yes_no")`, change itemDeleted from `Boolean` to `String`, and then set it to "Y" or "N" to see if those updates persist? Also check that no other columns are named "IS_DELETED" because that would lead to some issues.

Comment: The String fields are correctly persisted, only the Boolean YesNoType have an issue.

Comment: Very odd.... never had issues w/ Hibernate yes_no columns before... you could try the `@Convert` annotation instead: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: It's specifically with H2, it works fine in Oracle. The @Converter is one of the solution I thought also to work around.

Comment: The vast majority of our JUnits use H2, and we've had no issues with yes_no columns before. Realistically, the syntax should fit the ANSI standard, so it shouldn't matter which Hibernate dialect you choose or which database actually gets used. Can you add these 2 lines to your log4j properties to see what Hibernate is spitting out? `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and 
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`. That should give you the SQL and the bind variables